# How to get the value of an element by traversing the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am traversing the DOM in order to get the value of a table data cell. To be more specific, the following bit of traversing:

```
const nodeLis = target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes;
```

gets me a node list that contains:

```
NodeList 
0 #text " "
1 <td>title1</td>
2 #text " "
3 <td>title2</td>
4 #text " "
5 <td>title3</td>
6 #text " "
```

Now what I want to do is be able to get the values of the table data cells, specifically 'title1', 'title1' and 'title3'

Now I have tried to index into the childNodes list by doing

```
console.log(nodeLis[1]);
```

But this gets me

```
<td>title1</td>
```

and I'm not sure how to grab the actual title1 value from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(nodeLis[1].textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for that purpose. After that, you can iterate through the NodeList, and use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to get the individual child node values.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(x => {
  console.log(x.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

EDIT 1:
Instead of using `innerHTML`, you may want to use `textContent` instead, as explained on this other [link](https://gist.github.com/GoesToEleven/d3bdbb5b5e563fc9cf93) I found. Credits to @German for his answer on his post, and @Brilliand for pointing it out the improvements.

Comment: I would recommend combining this with German's answer.  innerHTML is not the best choice when what you're actually interested in is a piece of text.

Comment: @Brilliand Ah, thanks for pointing it out. I did a quick Google search about it just now, and found some explanation to it. `textContent` is indeed better!

Comment: It would be better to directly edit `textContent` into your code snippet, rather than adding a note saying that the code snippet is partially wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the content of the element by looking at the `innerHTML` property

```
console.log(nodeLis[1].innerHTML);
```